# Send multiple values dynamically with Ajax and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

- I have an unknown amount of clickable
  buttons. (generated)
- Every button is connected to
  multiple values that should be sent
  through the Ajax call.

**I found this to start with:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: parameters,
    success: function(msg){
    alert("nothing");
}
});
```

`data` contains parameters as far as I know. My parameters are different depending on what button that is clicked.

My guess is that I could use `this` somewhere? But what if I need to send 3 values?

```
<input type="button" id="unique-1"> <!-- With values 'test', 3 and 5 -->
<input type="button" id="unique-2"> <!-- With values 'doh2', 8 and 6 -->
```

I use PHP if you need that info.

Thanks!

Comment: how are the values bound to the node ?

Comment: No, not really. Should I put them in a rel-tag or something to be able to get to them?

Comment: Obviously you php script handles the random values already? So just use a javascript button to loop through each form value and send it in a POST string via the http send method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LEda5/). The button will find the form that it needs to submit, serialize the data, and alert that string. You would just need to then use that string as the parameter for the data option of the ajax call.

Comment: This should be what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way.

You could do something like this.  In each button, put the data (comma-seperated) in a html data attribute. One click: read it, split it, and then send it as an object.  On the php side, you'll receive an array of strings for `$_GET["data[]"]`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js"></script>

<input type="button" class="mybutton" data-mydata="1,2,really" />

<script>
$('.mybutton').click(function() {
  var parameters = $(this).attr('data-mydata').split(',');
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "some.php",
      data: {data:parameters},
      success: function(msg){
        alert("nothing");
      }
  });  
});
</script>
```

Fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/qdH7s/